# Random number within range for Float OR Int

Tags: c++, algorithm, gcc, stl, std

I'm making a templates function object that will generate a ranged random number. I know how to do that for either ints or floats. But my problem is that I want it to be able to generate a ranged random number of the type T.

So, since I want it to be able to return both floats and integers I can't use the % operator. This seem to work for float values. But if T is INT it will mess up the range.

```
return (_minValue + (T)rand() / ((T)RAND_MAX / (_maxValue - _minValue)));
```

There must be some mistake in that algorithm that I just can't seem to find at this hour.

Comment: Use the `<random>` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type `T` is an integer type, `(T)rand() / (T)RAND_MAX` will clearly be zero except for the rare case when `rand()` returns `RAND_MAX` (and `T` happens to be at least as `int`) in which case it will be one. Note that `rand()` is generally not a very good random number generator although the quality differs quite a bit between different implementations. You are probably best of to just use something from the `<random>` library (for my normal work I have very rarely a need for random numbers, i.e., I don't know how to use the components in this library immediately).

If you insist in using `rand()` your best option is probably to determine random values different for integers and floating points, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, bool = std::is_floating_point<T>::value>
struct random;
template <typename T>
struct random<T, true> {
    static T generate() { return /* floating point formula goes here */; }
};
template <typename T>
struct random<T, false> {
    static T generate() { return /* integer formula goes here */; }
};

template <typename T>
T random_range() { return random<T>::generate(); }
```

Comment: Thank you. Learned a lot form that answer. I forgot that rand() generates a number between 0 and 1. So what I ended up doing was letting it be a float all along and then I just cast it, like this:             return (T)(_minValue + (float)rand() / ((float)RAND_MAX / (_maxValue - _minValue)));

 It's not pretty, but it works.